# Entity framework Database First & EF Code First get Relation Object By ID

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, ef-database-first

in EF Database First  when change ForeignKey(CommodityGroupID) automatic Get CommodityGroup for Commodity object, But in EF Code First(4.3.1) not doing.

```
public class Commodity  
        {
            public int CommodityID { get; set; }
            public string MadeBy { get; set; }
            public decimal ServiceTimePrice { get; set; }
            public decimal QCPrice { get; set; }
            public int ServicePoint { get; set; }
            public string Note { get; set; }
            public int CommodityGroupID { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("CommodityGroupID")]
            public virtual CommodityGroup CommodityGroup { get; set; }
    }
    public class CommodityGroup
    { 
        public int CommodityGroupID { get; set; }
        public string CommodityGroupName { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }

    }
```

this Property defined in   Edmx file (database first), i Should define this code in ef code first?

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public EntityReference<CommodityGroup> CommodityGroupReference
{
    get
    {
        return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<CommodityGroup>("GaamRepairModel.FK_Commodity_CommodityGroup", "CommodityGroup");
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value != null))
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<CommodityGroup>("GaamRepairModel.FK_Commodity_CommodityGroup", "CommodityGroup", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled lazy loading ?

Comment: Can you please post your code which changes/gets data?

Comment: yes , LazyLoadingEnabled= true

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting a change tracking proxy.   You want the CommodityGroup navigation property to update automatically when the FK is changed correct?

See [this post on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx) for details about the change tracking proxy.

This [post on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835846.aspx) shows some code on how to test of your proxy object is being created properly.

Is this a new object?  If so, you'll need to call the CreateObject function on your DbSet, not use the New Commodity().

Comment: i tested  and isProxy() returned true.